# API Opensky Network impossible to access data

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, restful-url

OpenSky-Network is an API for aircraft positionning datas around the world. Wonderfull to play with Openlayers-3... but! (because there is a but!)

With JavaScript, I'm trying to access some variables of the JSON data at [this URL](https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?time=1458564121&icao24=3c6444)

I'm really blocked. It's accessible with simple naviguation in Firefox, not with JavaScript.

It seems really stupid because its working with other APIs like [this one](http://ipinfo.io/213.32.89.142/json), or other one like Wikipedia, Wikidata, Nominatim for Openlayers-3.

I'm really asking myself why this is not working just for OpenSky-Network. The only thing I saw is that Firefox shows me a cross-domain problem, but I'm sure there is a solution.

I have tried many techniques:

**Tech1**

```
$.getJSON( url , function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Tech2**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

**Tech3**

```
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     crossDomain : true,
     success:function(xhr, json){               
         alert("Success ");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
 });
```

**Tech4**

```
var xhr = null;
var response = null; 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.info("state changed");

    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            response = xhr.responseText;
            console.info("response="+response);
        }
    }
    else {}
};

xhr.open("GET", url,true);
xhr.send(null);
```

With all these and other techniques, I can't get the JSON data at the opensky url api. I mean i want to use it as a JavaScript variable but i can't.

It's really frustrating because in the inspector tool (F12 key in Firefox) i can see the JSON object and the values. There is a "Same Origin" policy problem and then i don't have the variable. What is the problem? I really can't understand the point of this "Same Origin" policy concept, english is not my native language.

According to the limitations section of the API documentaton i can do it without registrating.

> Anonymous are those users who access the API without using credentials. The limitations for anonymous users are:
>
> - Anonymous users can only get the most recent state vectors, i.e. the time parameter will be ignored.
> - Anonymous users can only retrieve data with a time resultion of 10 seconds. That means, the API will return state vectors for time now−(now mod 10)

Thus, I have a couple questions:

1. Can I access the variables at the URL of the API of OpenSky-Network with JavaScript?
2. Why is this specific URL having issues?
3. What is the problem with "Same Origin" policy just for this url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the OpenSky developers.

As codepearlex already mentioned, the OpenSky API did not allow CORS. We have recently enabled this, so you should now be able to access the API from within a browser and any domain.

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated above the **same origin policy** (SOP) is the problem here.

> It seems really stupid because its working with other APIs like [this one](http://ipinfo.io/213.32.89.142/json), or other one like Wikipedia, Wikidata, Nominatim for Openlayers-3.
>
> 3. What is the problem with "Same Origin" policy just for this url?

When a server receives an incoming request it can check the `Origin` field in the request header and either allow or disallow the request with respect to the SOP. Note that "disallow" does not mean the server is denying the data but rather not setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field in the response header, causing your browser to block the request. In order to have the browser allow the request the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field in the response header must be either equal to the `Origin` field or `*`.
The API you gave as an example (http://ipinfo.io/213.32.89.142/json) returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, therefore allowing requests from every origin.

> 2. Why is this specific URL having issues?

The OpenSky API does not include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field in the response header which means that your browser blocks the request and denies access to the payload from the server (if the script issuing the requestwas loaded from a different origin, your server). As you noticed in the debug console the data is there but your browser restricts access.

> Can I access the variables at the URL of the API of OpenSky-Network with JavaScript?

There recently has been a similar [issue](https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/issues/6) on GitHub. Cross origin requests will not be available any time soon. You will have to proxy the API requests with your webserver.

In case you are experiencing any difficulties with our services in the future I would recommend posting your question to the [OpenSky Forum](https://opensky-network.org/forum/index). I only found this thread by chance. Questions in the Forum will notify all OpenSky administrators and enable us to respond as quickly as possible.